# Cursor is not blinking

Tags: text-cursor

My cursor does not blink at all and it is hard to find my place.  I use Word 7 with Worldox.  How can I get my cursor to blink?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Keyboard and there see the cursor blink rate.

[image]

it is towards NONE then it will not blink in text editors..

if it is correct then check the editor settings or the mouse properties in the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a cursor and if so, then Niranjan Kala's answer probably did it. But if you do not have a cursor at all, try selecting <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. This has worked for me on various applications I use where the cursor doesn't appear in inside a field I've clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

@Dennis is wrong.

The correct location is Control Panel - Keyboard.  The slider moved all the way to the left turns off blinking. Move it all the way to the right.

As a side note, you can go to Ease of Access Center under Control Panel and make the cursor wider.